# Работа MySql базы зависит от количества строк(данных) в ней? (Статистика)

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, производительность, статистика

Нужно сделать статистику сайта. Думаю при загрузке страницы добавлять строку в таблицу (stat) с данными (id, ip, user, url, session, date). Все это прикручивается в готовый проект (2500-3400 в просмотров сутки). Итак ето ~3 000 записей в сутку, за месяц ~90 000 записей. Станет ли база дольше грузиться? интересует не выборка этих данных, а вообще робота сайта.

И может будут рекомендации как сделать статистику по другому *"правильно"*...
Извените за мой Русский

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Google Analytics (сокращённо GA) — бесплатный сервис, предоставляемый Google для создания детальной статистики посетителей веб-сайтов. Статистика собирается на сервере Google, пользователь только размещает JS-код на страницах своего сайта.

[Добро пожаловать!](http://www.google.com/analytics/)

Comment: Спасибо! Я знаю эти сервисы, но мне нужно именно своя статистика... Кстати нету Api для PHP експорта из Google Analytics?

Comment: Интернет-магазин. посещяемость в среднем 1000 уников. Около 5000 просмотров-вызовов функции записи в таблицу статистики данных примерно как Вы привели в вопросе. Вести статистику начал больше 2 лет назад. Перед записью в бд поставил фильтр чтобы не записывать обращения поисковых ботов (иначе большая половина записей была бы от них). Выборка посещяемости по дате происходит 2-3 секунды. Индекс на поле с датой проставлен. Железо core2duo 2.5Gh/2gb DDR2/ 4 HDD в RAID 1 0 . Ищите уже готовые варианты скриптов статистики. Ибо при изобретении велосипеда не получится учесть все нюансы.